# Get rows from table with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a database .mdf-file, callded SportsStore.mdf. In this database file, I have created a table and filled It with rows. Now Im trying to get this rows and print It to a view with Entity Framework.

Im trying to use a repository pattern for my work with entity framework.

In my model domain called SportsStore.domain, I have three important files: Entities/Product.cs, Concrete/EFDbContext.cs, Concrete/EFProductRepository.cs and Abstract/IProductsRepository.cs

IProductsRepository Is a Interface that EFProductRepository implements.

IProductsRepository:

```
using SportsStore.domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

EFDbContext:

```
using SportsStore.domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    //Associate the model with the database
    //This class then automatically defines a property for each table in the database that I want to work with. 
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EFProductRepository:

```
using SportsStore.domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; } 
        }
    }
}
```

I also use dependency injection with Ninject to bind IProductRepository to EFProductRepository:

```
kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
```

Here Is my controller:

```
using SportsStore.domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        //Declar the dependency on IProductRepository
        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            this.repository = productRepository;
        }
        // GET: Product

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Products.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, the controller Is using IProductRepository interface.

Here Is my View:

```
@using SportsStore.domain.Entities
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}
           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description);
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price);
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
           }
```

Connectionstring:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The problem I have is that when I run my application, nothing is printed out. No error messages are shown or nothing.

How can I go on with my problem? Where should I look?

Comment: Where is your connection string that refer to your `.mdf-file database` ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Check my updated question

Comment: You say that you created an MDF data file but you are connecting to an attached database, not a data file.  Please describe EXACTLY how you created the database.  For the data file to be relevant, you'd have had to actually add that file to your project.  Given your connection string, you probably would have had to create an attached database in Management Studio.  Please describe EXACTLY how you created this database.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: And there we have the problem. How do I connect to the database file instead? Im new to this.

Comment: @Bryan `Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=YOUR_MDF_PATH; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Should I replace the Data Source with Driver?

Comment: @AramKocharyan: I solved It, thank you very much :)

Comment: @AramKocharyan, you only use `Driver` for an ODBC connection, which this is not.

Comment: @Bryan, I'm not sure what you did but all you needed to do was remove the `InitialCatalog` and replace it with `AttachDbFilename`, then provide the file path in place of the database name.